# I get "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port" error while trying to use Kubernetes?

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, connection, config

I am using Ubuntu 22.04LTS and just installed Kubernetes following this instruction: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/ on my Ubuntu desktop machine.

When I try this command `sudo kubectl cluster-info`  for example, I get this result:

```
To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

So I searched through the internet and found this command `kubectl config view` and this is the result:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters: null
contexts: null
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: null
```

Moreover in this directory `/etc/kubernetes` there is only an empty folder named `manifest`.

So I tried `sudo kubeadm init` but I got:

```
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.25.4
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
    [WARNING Swap]: swap is enabled; production deployments should disable swap unless testing the NodeSwap feature gate of the kubelet
    [WARNING SystemVerification]: missing optional cgroups: blkio
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR CRI]: container runtime is not running: output: E1207 13:27:13.819798   50381 remote_runtime.go:948] "Status from runtime service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1alpha2.RuntimeService"
time="2022-12-07T13:27:13-08:00" level=fatal msg="getting status of runtime: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1alpha2.RuntimeService"
, error: exit status 1
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

I also tried `sudo kubeadm config images pull --v=5` and got the following result/error:

```
I1207 17:14:06.585276   62896 initconfiguration.go:116] detected and using CRI socket: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
I1207 17:14:06.585610   62896 interface.go:432] Looking for default routes with IPv4 addresses
I1207 17:14:06.585617   62896 interface.go:437] Default route transits interface "wlp2s0"
I1207 17:14:06.585904   62896 interface.go:209] Interface wlp2s0 is up
I1207 17:14:06.585979   62896 interface.go:257] Interface "wlp2s0" has 2 addresses :[192.168.1.2/24 fe80::7a46:dd7e:145:d5e2/64].
I1207 17:14:06.586002   62896 interface.go:224] Checking addr  192.168.1.2/24.
I1207 17:14:06.586008   62896 interface.go:231] IP found 192.168.1.2
I1207 17:14:06.586032   62896 interface.go:263] Found valid IPv4 address 192.168.1.2 for interface "wlp2s0".
I1207 17:14:06.586037   62896 interface.go:443] Found active IP 192.168.1.2 
I1207 17:14:06.586088   62896 kubelet.go:196] the value of KubeletConfiguration.cgroupDriver is empty; setting it to "systemd"
I1207 17:14:06.589640   62896 version.go:187] fetching Kubernetes version from URL: https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt
exit status 1
output: E1207 17:14:07.075957   62948 remote_image.go:222] "PullImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1alpha2.ImageService" image="registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.25.4"
time="2022-12-07T17:14:07-08:00" level=fatal msg="pulling image: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1alpha2.ImageService"
, error
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/util/runtime.(*CRIRuntime).PullImage
    cmd/kubeadm/app/util/runtime/runtime.go:138
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.PullControlPlaneImages
    cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/config.go:326
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdConfigImagesPull.func1
    cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/config.go:312
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:856
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:974
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:902
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
    cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50
main.main
    cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1594
failed to pull image "registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.25.4"
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.PullControlPlaneImages
    cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/config.go:327
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdConfigImagesPull.func1
    cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/config.go:312
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:856
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:974
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:902
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
    cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50
main.main
    cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1594
```

I don't know what is the problem and how can I resolve it?
please let me know if there is more information good to add.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are some issues in /etc/containerd/config.toml file. Please check your newly added item in this file. Did you comment the following code in  /etc/containerd/config.toml file.
`#disabled_plugins = ["cri"]`

`#plugins.cri.systemd_cgroup = true`